# crystal report free edition in which version of MS Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

which edition of MS Visual Studio contains free redistributable edition of Crystal Reports? Also, is CR included in latest versions of Visual Studio?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can distribute Crystal Reports made with Visual Studio Professional at no extra cost above what you pay for Visual Studio. As mentioned you do need to have, at least, the Professional SKU and Crystal Reports is available in the last three editions of Visual Studio Pro(2005, 2008, and 2010).

Comment: i want a free edition of vs also, which one is free? and a free redistributable version of CR ? which to download

Comment: Visual Studio 2010 Express is free but it does not come with Crystal Reports. Currently there is no free version of Crystal Reports available although you should be able to get a trial version from SAP's site (The current owner of CR).

Comment: You may want to consider SQL Reporting services, which come with SQL Server Express 2010 and, as far as I know, can be used with Visual Studio Express 2010.

Answer (score 1):

Crystal Reports is not bundled with VisualStudio 2010. I don't think there is a free version any more. There are open source alternatives (BIRT, Jasper, Pentaho, SSRS Express, etc) but the learning curve on them is expensive in terms of your time.

Comment: While CR is no longer bundled with VS you can download it free from SAP's site http://www.businessobjects.com/jump/xi/crvs2010/default.asp and distribute the reports that you build with VS freely with your applications.

Comment: @BukHix: sir, the url you mentioned, does it provides the free edition of CR? i mean that for development of new reports and for distribution also, is it free?

Comment: Again there is no free edition of Crystal Reports. You either have to purchase it outright or download it from the link above provided you are a licensed user of Visual Studio Pro (minimum). There is, however, a trial version that you can download from SAP's site but will not work after the trial period expires.